# jquery listen for database changes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a list of projects and tasks on a page. I am looking to simply show when someone is editing a task record. Is there a fairly simple way to have jquery listen for database changes and mark a row "locked" I am not saying it would disable anything, just indicate to the user someone is making a change.

I could then have the user reload the page to get the updated data to display when the change had been saved.

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: you can do that using ajax calls and having the locking logic on the server side. Ping continuously from the client to see whether the task has been locked.

Comment: Thank you. Just curios if i have 100's of tasks couldn't that eat a lot of client side memory? Or are their any examples of a lightweight way to do that?

Comment: make one ajax request asking for all locked tasks in the list given. this way one ajax call will be sufficient.

Comment: If your server is configured right, you could use a websocket. Like Stackoverflow. Updated are continuously sent when something updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval()` should do the trick.  Simply have your JS ping the back end every so often, to see if the db is still locked.

Also, with jQuery and AJAX, you wouldn't need the user to refresh the page if it became unlocked.  Pseudocode:

```
setInterval($.get(attrs to whatever back end script that will actually do the heavy lifting), 5000); // ping every five seconds

// in $.get, you can display different things based on whether or not the back end
// response says it's locked
```